# Written document from meeting in spite of a contract

Tags: contract-law

I resigned from a company and it was documented in a meeting with my district manager that I would receive compensation for the way I left. It changed the way I left the organization as I had 3 different ways to leave, but as I am leaving, I am being told the meeting document is incorrect in regards to the original written contract. Does this meeting document supersede my original written contract? Do I have rights in regards to this meeting document given to me?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the written terms of a contract prevail. However, the terms of a contract can be subsequently modified, and a modification can be oral or in writing. You are entitled to rely on such a promise and act accordingly. If they had promised one benefit and 1 second later said "No, wait, we can't do that according to your contract", you would not have relied on their promise in making your decision. But you did, to your detriment. You can use the doctrine of promissory estoppel to keep them from pointing to the original document, saying "We didn't mean it". There could be a question whether the person who said this was an authorized agent of the company (i.e. the janitor can't give you his promise that you have a more lucrative option).

Comment: The question is rather weather the person had ostensible authority- actual authority is irrelevant.